# Is there possibility to use Json reference in MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use reference inside document to document's value.

Does MongoDB provides value reference like python's `JSONref` inside single document?

```
{
    "meta": {
        "name": "myname"
    },
    "ftp":{
        "name": {"$ref":"#/meta/name"}
    }
}
```

When load in Python, `ftp["name"]` will contains value of `meta["name"]`.

So I can modify value on one place in document and get all replacement of `$ref.`
I can't figure out, if such reference is possible in MomgoDB.

Comment: It does not, In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document. You can have the same effect without need of that.